# Uncrustify Formatter error when code contains single hash characters

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uncrustify

I am using the Uncrustify plugin for Xcode5 (BBUncrustifyPlugin) to format my code nicely. However when formatting the active file it gives the errors:

```
Uncrustify Formatter error:
Parsing: XDImageViewController.m as language OC
XDImageViewController.m:33 Unmatched NEWLINE
```

Looking at this line all I have is a single hash # followed by a new line. like so:

```
#
#pragma mark - Section header
#
```

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to get Uncrustify to ignore this error or work around it? I don't see why a hash should cause problems.

Thanks.

Comment: May be it's because you are using empty Macros `#` that does nothing? That's why Unrucstify pays your attention on it.

Comment: Yes but I want a way to make it ignore these empty macros. Why would an empty macro cause Uncrustify to throw this error?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (a) it'll never be answered; (b) using a hash mark is unconventional in C; and (c) uncrustify doesn't have the feature to format blank macros. The question's author would be better off using a blank line or double-slash comment.